# DialogPreference - error

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I am trying to create a dialog preference as follows

```
<DialogPreference
    android:key="cachePref"
    android:dialogMessage="Testing message"
    android:dialogTitle="Title Test"
    android:positiveButtonText="positive"
    android:summary="Clear images save to disk"
    android:title="Clear Image Cache" />
```

But when the activity runs it force closes with the following error

```
11-01 01:21:18.820: E/AndroidRuntime(19644): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bakasura/com.bakasura.SettingsPreferences}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #71: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like [Android Issue 3972: *InstantiationException when using DialogPreference*](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3972):

`DialogPreference` always was an abstract class and as such it should not have been able to be instantiated -- but a bug in reflection code allowed to do so anyway up to Android 1.6. After that, it correctly throws an exception.

A work around is to create a custom class extending `DialogPreference` and use that instead as [suggested in comment 9](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3972#c9) of the issue.